# Best way to load data in MySQL DB using JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

Here's a sample dataset of a much larger data file, I need to load into mysql db.  The problem is the dataset is too large to manually add/append the insert statements and put the commas at the right locations.

`E  1
T   2006-11-02 22:01:34
U   6   andrevan
N   70  node_ue
V   1   62  2004-09-11 05:50:00 node
V   1   27  2004-09-11 06:13:00 slowking
V   1   11  2004-09-11 06:50:00 merovingian
V   1   34  2004-09-11 12:11:00 norm
V   1   10  2004-09-11 13:30:00 anÃ¡rion
V   1   55  2004-09-11 15:20:00 thecustomoflife
V   1   28  2004-09-11 15:21:00 neutrality
V   1   8   2004-09-11 16:56:00 lst27
V   1   63  2004-09-11 18:00:00 zchangu
V   1   5   2004-09-11 19:51:00 orthogonal
V   1   26  2004-09-12 03:04:00 grunt
V   -1  25  2004-09-12 03:46:00 blankfaze
V   1   56  2004-09-12 22:00:00 guanaco
V   1   64  2004-09-12 22:51:00 beau99
V   1   19  2004-09-13 00:51:00 ffirehorse
V   1   20  2004-09-13 01:27:00 michael
V   1   7   2004-09-14 19:49:00 texture
V   1   65  2004-09-16 05:01:00 friedmilk
V   1   66  2004-09-17 13:56:00 ezhiki
V   1   39  2004-09-18 07:34:00 squash`

Can someone please suggest the best way to load this into mysql db using JDBC?

Thanks!

Comment: look at the first row, how do you know if the 2nd entry is for second column or third column?

Comment: Hi max, it is for the 2nd column.

Comment: I wouldn't do this with JDBC at all. I would somehow convert it to CSV and use the Import CSV feature of MySQL, if it has one, or of the HeidiSQL client if it doesn't.

Comment: Read say 100 rows at a time and batch insert them.

Comment: You say "the dataset is too large to manually" - why not use awk? I would first use a script reformat it so there is data in all fields. Then use another awk script to convert it to a CSV or to INSERT statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to use MySQL LOAD DATA INFILE (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/load-data.html). Using this method, you can tell it to use tab delimited format and skip the first x rows.

If you need to run this from Java, you can wrap the call in Java code. For example on how this is done, you can see how Pentaho project is doing it: https://github.com/pentaho/pentaho-kettle/blob/master/engine/src/org/pentaho/di/trans/steps/mysqlbulkloader/MySQLBulkLoader.java/ Or this simple blog entry: http://jeffrick.com/2010/03/23/bulk-insert-into-a-mysql-database/.

Speaking from experience, this is definitely not a job for JDBC as it will cause too much performance bottleneck. However if for whatever reason you need to use JDBC, just make sure that you use PreparedStatement and batch the rows. Spring has a very good implementation that you can leverage. For example on this use: http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-jdbctemplate-batchupdate-example/. Of course you also need to make sure that you stream the file and read line by line accordingly to avoid out of memory.